# A monad for building test data

Tags: haskell, monads

OK, so I'm trying to write a monad for building test data, but I can't quite get it to work how I want it. It looks something like this:

```
runBuildM :: [i] -> BuildM i o x -> [o]
-- Given a list of i, build a list of o.

source :: BuildM i o i
-- Fetch unique i.

yield :: o -> BuildM i o ()
-- Return a new o to the caller.

gather :: BuildM i o x -> BuildM i o o
-- Fetch every possible o from sub-computation.

local :: BuildM i o x -> BuildM i o x
-- Isolate any source invocations from the rest of the code.
```

In other words, it's a supply monad, writer monad and list monad. The idea is that I can write something like this:

```
build_tests depth = do
  local $ do
    v <- source
    yield v
    yield (map toLower v)
  yield "[]"
  yield "()"
  when (depth > 2) $ do
    t1 <- gather $ build_tests (depth-1)
    yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ ")"
    yield $ "[" ++ t1 ++ "]"
    t2 <- gather $ build_tests (depth-1)
    yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ "," ++ t2 ++ ")"
```

The idea is to generate all possible combinations of data. You can do that just using list comprehensions, but the result ends up syntactically awful. This is *much* more readable. Unfortunately, it doesn't actually *work*...

The problem seems to boil down to the `local` function not behaving correctly. The *intention* is for any `source` calls in the sub-computation to have no effect outside of it. (I.e., subsequent calls to `source` from outside the `local` block get the first token again.) However, what my implementation of `local` *actually* does is reset the next token for *everything* (i.e., including the contents of the sub-computation). This is clearly incorrect, but I cannot for the life of me bend my mind around how to make it work correctly.

The fact that I'm having this much trouble getting the code to work as required probably means the actual internal representation of my monad is just *wrong*. Can anybody take a stab at implementing this correctly?

---

**EDIT:** I should perhaps have realised this, but I didn't actually specify the expected result I'm trying to get. The above code is supposed to produce this:

```
["A", "a", "[]", "()", "(A)", "(a)", "[A]", "[a]", "(A, B)", "(A, b)", "(a, B)", "(a, b)"]
```

It's not super-critical that the results appear in exactly this order. I'd like the single cases to appear before the compound ones, but I'm not too fussed exactly what order the compounds appear. The rule is that the same variable never appears twice in any individual expression.

If we allow the depth to be a bit deeper, we additionally get terms such as

```
"((A))", "([A])", "[(A)]", "((A, B), C)", "(A, (B, C))"
```

and so on.

---

It's clearly broken, but here's what I have so far:

```
newtype BuildM i o x = BuildM ([i] -> SEQ.Seq ([i], SEQ.Seq o, x))

instance Functor (BuildM i o) where
  fmap uf (BuildM sf) =
    BuildM $ \ is0 -> do
      (is1, os, x) <- sf is0
      return (is1, os, uf x)

instance Applicative (BuildM i o) where
  pure x = BuildM $ \ is0 -> return (is0, SEQ.empty, x)

  BuildM sf1 <*> BuildM sf2 =
    BuildM $ \ is1 -> do
      (is2, os2, f) <- sf1 is1
      (is3, os3, x) <- sf2 is2
      return (is3, os2 >< os3, f x)

instance Monad (BuildM i o) where
  return = pure

  BuildM sf1 >>= uf =
    BuildM $ \ is1 -> do
      (is2, os2, x) <- sf1 is1
      let BuildM sf2 = uf x
      (is3, os3, y) <- sf2 is2
      return (is3, os2 >< os3, y)

runBuildM :: [i] -> BuildM i o x -> [o]
runBuildM is0 (BuildM sf) =
  toList $ do
    (is, os, x) <- sf is0
    os

source :: BuildM i o i
source =
  BuildM $ \ is ->
    if null is
      then error "AHC.Tests.TestBuilder.source: end of input"
      else return (tail is, SEQ.empty, head is)

yield :: o -> BuildM i o ()
yield o = BuildM $ \ is -> return (is, SEQ.singleton o, () )

gather :: BuildM i o x -> BuildM i o' o
gather (BuildM sf1) =
  BuildM $ \ is1 -> do
    (is2, os2, _) <- sf1 is1
    o <- os2
    return (is2, SEQ.empty, o)

local :: BuildM i o x -> BuildM i o ()
local (BuildM sf1) =
  BuildM $ \ is1 ->
    let os = do (is2, os2, x) <- sf1 is1; os2
    in  return (is1, os, () )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reinvent [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) and some [nice syntax for building lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32175554/414413). The problem is much simpler than how you characterize it. The source of strings can be completely separated from building the structures.

You want to generate structures that draw symbols from some source. Without worrying about the source, let's build the structures. Each structure is a `Pipe` that will draw from some source and `yield` strings to concatenate together to build the expression.

```
import Data.Char

import Data.Functor.Identity

import Pipes.Core
import Pipes ((>->))
import qualified Pipes as P
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

build_structures :: Int -> [Pipe String String Identity ()]
build_structures depth = gather $ do
    yield $ P.take 1
    yield $ P.map (map toLower) >-> P.take 1
    when (depth > 2) $ do
        t1 <- lift $ build_structures (depth - 1)
        yield $ P.yield "(" >> t1 >> P.yield ")"
        yield $ P.yield "[" >> t1 >> P.yield "]"
        t2 <- lift $ build_structures (depth - 1)
        yield $ P.yield "(" >> t1 >> P.yield "," >> t2 >> P.yield ")"
```

This code uses the [`ContT` yield trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32175554/414413) from the continuation answer.

We run one of these structures by feeding it the symbols and concatenating the results.

```
run :: Pipe String String Identity () -> String
run p = concat . P.toList $ P.each symbols >-> p

-- an infinite source of unique symbols
symbols :: [String]
symbols = drop 1 symbols'
    where
        symbols' = [""] ++ do
            tail <- symbols'
            first <- ['A'..'Z']
            return (first : tail)
```

The examples produce the desired strings. I'll leave producing the two special cases `"[]"` and `"()"`, which do not appear in recursive terms, as an exercise.

```
import Data.Functor

main = do
    putStrLn "Depth 2"
    print $ run <$> build_structures 2
    putStrLn "Depth 3"
    print $ run <$> build_structures 3
    putStrLn "Depth 4"
    print $ run <$> build_structures 4
```

This results in

```
Depth 2
["A","a"]
Depth 3
["A","a","(A)","[A]","(A,B)","(A,b)","(a)","[a]","(a,B)","(a,b)"]
Depth 4
["A","a","(A)","[A]","(A,B)","(A,b)","(A,(B))","(A,[B])","(A,(B,C))","(A,(B,c))","(A,(b))","(A,[b])","(A,(b,C))","(A,(b,c))","(a)","[a]","(a,B)","(a,b)","(a,(B))","(a,[B])","(a,(B,C))","(a,(B,c))","(a,(b))","(a,[b])",...
```

Comment: Having waded through the extensive documentation for `Pipes`, it appears it does in fact do the thing I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to reinvent [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes). Your `source` and `yield` are pipes `await` and `yield`.  The other two concerns you are trying to handle are a `ReaderT` and a `WriterT` respectively. If you put the entire list of inputs in the environment of the `ReaderT` you can run `local` sub computations that start over at the beginning of the list. You can collect all of the results from a sub-computation by adding a `WriterT` layer to collect the output.

For the nice syntax with `gather` you are trying to recreate `ListT`.

#### Pipes, Readers, and Writers

We're going to use all of the following in very short order.

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Foldable

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Morph
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader hiding (local)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict

import Pipes.Core
import Pipes ((>->))
import qualified Pipes as P
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

import Pipes.Lift (runWriterP, runReaderP)
```

Your builder is a `Pipe i o` over a `Reader [i]` which allows you to reset at the beginning of the input. We will define two versions of it, `BuildT` which is a monad transformer, and `BuildM` which is a monad. `BuildM` is jsut the transformer applied to `Identity`.

```
type BuildT e i o m r = Pipe i o (ReaderT e m) r
type BuildM e i o   r = BuildT e i o Identity r
```

`local` runs a builder feeding it the entire input read from the environment. We might want to give this a different name to avoid conflicting with `local` defined for `ReaderT`

```
local :: (Monad m, Foldable f) => BuildT (f i) i o m () -> Proxy a' a () o (ReaderT (f i) m) ()
local subDef = do
    e <- lift ask
    hoist lift $ runReaderP e $
        P.each e >->
        subDef
```

To collect the results of the sub computations, we take advantage of the fact that pipes are so pure that you can swap out the underlying monad provided you have a natural transformation `forall x. m x -> n x`. The proxies from pipes have an [`MFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) instance that provides a function `hoist :: (forall x. m x -> n x) -> Proxy a' a b' b m r -> Proxy a' a b' b n r`; it lets us lift all of the underlying monad operations under a pipe to use the pipe over another transformer, in this case `WriterT`.

```
collect :: (Monad m) => Proxy a' a () b m r -> Proxy a' a c' c m ([b], r)
collect subDef = do
    (r, w) <- runWriterP $
        hoist lift subDef //> \x -> lift $ tell (++[x])
    return (w [], r)
```

To run a builder we feed it all of the input from the environment, provide the initial environment, collect the results, and run the entire pipe.

```
runBuildT :: (Monad m) => [i] -> BuildT [i] i o m () -> m [o]
runBuildT e = runEffect . fmap fst . collect . runReaderP e . local
```

Running the monad instead of the transformer is just

```
runBuildM :: [i] -> BuildM [i] i o () -> [o]
runBuildM e = runIdentity . runBuildT e
```

#### ListT

This section lets us use `do`-notation when generating all combinations of things. It's equivalent to using pipes' [`for`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes.html#v:for) in place of each `>>=` and `yield` in place of each `return`.

The syntax that `gather`s all of the results from a sub computation is reinventing [`ListT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes.html#t:ListT). a `ListT m a` holds a `Producer a m ()` that only returns data downstream. Pipes that get data from upstream and return data downstream don't fit into the `Producer b m ()`. This will take a bit of conversion.

We can convert a `Proxy` that has both an upstream and a downstream interface into one with only a downstream interface wrapped around another proxy with the upstream interface. To do so, we hoist the underlying monad into our new inner upstream proxy, then replace all of the `request`s in the outer downstream proxy with `request`s lifted from the inner upstream proxy.

```
floatRespond :: (Monad m) => Proxy a' a b' b m r -> Proxy c' c b' b (Proxy a' a d' d m) r
floatRespond = (lift . request >\\) . hoist lift
```

These can be converted into a `ListT`. We'll discard any returned data to get a more polymorphic type.

```
gather :: (Monad m) => Proxy a' a () b m r -> P.ListT (Proxy a' a c' c m) b
gather = P.Select . floatRespond . (>>= return . const ())
```

Using `ListT` is a bit cumbersome to use; you need an `mplus` between `return`s to get both outputs. It's frequently convenient to shove a proxy into a `ListT` so you can `lift . yield` instead of `return`ing. We are going to discard all our `ListT` results an rely on the output coming from `lift . yield.`enumerate`just runs a`ListT` wrapped around anything, discarding all the results

```
enumerate = P.runListT
```

#### Example

We're now equipped to write and run your example. I thing you mean for `source` to get one value from the source and for `yield` to return one value. If you don't need to be able to get values one at a time your question is over-specified and this answer is overkill.

```
source = P.await
yield = P.yield
```

In the example, where we use `gather` to build lists, we run that portion of the code with `enumerate` and yield results with `lift . yield`.

```
import Data.Char

build_tests :: Monad m => Int -> BuildT [String] String String m ()
build_tests depth = do
  local $ do
    v <- source
    yield $ v
    yield $ (map toLower v)
  yield "[]"
  yield "()"
  when (depth > 2) $ enumerate $ do
    t1 <- gather $ build_tests (depth-1)
    lift . yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ ")"
    lift . yield $ "[" ++ t1 ++ "]"
    t2 <- gather $ build_tests (depth-1)
    lift . yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ "," ++ t2 ++ ")"
```

If we run this example with the input `["A", "B"]` the "B" input is never used because `source` is only ever used once inside each `local`.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Depth 2"
    print =<< runBuildT ["A", "B"] (build_tests 2)
    putStrLn "Depth 3"
    print =<< runBuildT ["A", "B"] (build_tests 3)
```

The output for depths less than 4 is small enough to repeat here.

```
["A","a","[]","()"]
Depth 3
["A","a","[]","()","(A)","[A]","(A,A)","(A,a)","(A,[])","(A,())","(a)","[a]","(a,A)","(a,a)","(a,[])","(a,())","([])","[[]]","([],A)","([],a)","([],[])","([],())","(())","[()]","((),A)","((),a)","((),[])","((),())"]
```

#### This might be overkill

I suspect that you might have meant for `source` to get everything from the source.

```
source = gather P.cat
yield = P.yield
```

If we use this for the example instead of getting a single item from the source we'll `enumerate` the first `local` block and yield results by `return`ing in `ListT`.

```
build_tests :: Monad m => Int -> BuildT [String] String String m ()
build_tests depth = do
  local $ enumerate $ do
    v <- source
    lift . yield $ v
    lift . yield $ (map toLower v)
  yield "[]"
  yield "()"
  when (depth > 2) $ enumerate $ do
    t1 <- gather $ build_tests (depth-1)
    lift . yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ ")"
    lift . yield $ "[" ++ t1 ++ "]"
    t2 <- gather $ build_tests (depth-1)
    lift . yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ "," ++ t2 ++ ")"
```

This uses both source values when we run the example with two sources.

```
Depth 2
["A","a","B","b","[]","()"]
Depth 3
["A","a","B","b","[]","()","(A)","[A]","(A,A)","(A,a)","(A,B)","(A,b)","(A,[])","(A,())","(a)","[a]","(a,A)","(a,a)","(a,B)","(a,b)","(a,[])","(a,())","(B)","[B]","(B,A)","(B,a)","(B,B)","(B,b)","(B,[])","(B,())","(b)","[b]","(b,A)","(b,a)","(b,B)","(b,b)","(b,[])","(b,())","([])","[[]]","([],A)","([],a)","([],B)","([],b)","([],[])","([],())","(())","[()]","((),A)","((),a)","((),B)","((),b)","((),[])","((),())"]
```

If you never get a single value from the source you could just use `ListT (ReaderT [i] m) o` instead. You might still want a proxy to avoid messing around with `mplus`.

Comment: OK, it's going to me a take a while to digest this. But I notice the result is wrong. The expected result is a bit too big to fit in a comment; I'll go edit it into the question...

Answer (score 2):

If [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32169971/414413) is overkill,  the continuation monad transformer provides a convenient way to construct any [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) values.

The continuation monad lets us easily capture the idea of doing something `mplus` the as yet unknown remainder.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont

once :: MonadPlus m => m a -> ContT a m ()
once m = ContT $ \k -> m `mplus` k ()
```

Yielding a result is just returning it once.

```
yield :: MonadPlus m => a -> ContT a m ()
yield = once . return
```

We can gather up all the results by sticking `mzero` at the end.

```
gather :: MonadPlus m => ContT a m r -> m a
gather m = runContT m (const mzero)
```

Your example is written in terms of `yield`, `gather`, `once`, and `lift`.

```
import Data.Char

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

build_tests :: MonadPlus m => m String -> Int -> ContT String m ()
build_tests source = go
  where
    go depth = do
      once . gather $ do
        v <- lift source
        yield v
        yield (map toLower v)
      yield "[]"
      yield "()"
      when (depth > 2) $ do
        t1 <- lift . gather $ go (depth-1)
        yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ ")"
        yield $ "[" ++ t1 ++ "]"
        t2 <- lift . gather $ go (depth-1)
        yield $ "(" ++ t1 ++ "," ++ t2 ++ ")"

main = print . gather $ build_tests ["A", "B"] 3
```

This outputs the following:

```
Depth 2
["A","a","B","b","[]","()"]
Depth 3
["A","a","B","b","[]","()","(A)","[A]","(A,A)","(A,a)","(A,B)","(A,b)","(A,[])","(A,())","(a)","[a]","(a,A)","(a,a)","(a,B)","(a,b)","(a,[])","(a,())","(B)","[B]","(B,A)","(B,a)","(B,B)","(B,b)","(B,[])","(B,())","(b)","[b]","(b,A)","(b,a)","(b,B)","(b,b)","(b,[])","(b,())","([])","[[]]","([],A)","([],a)","([],B)","([],b)","([],[])","([],())","(())","[()]","((),A)","((),a)","((),B)","((),b)","((),[])","((),())"]
```

I've taken the liberty of getting rid of the requirement to read the original source from the environment for simplicity. You can add a `ReaderT` to the transformer stack to get it back. I also haven't chosen a list transfomer for you, the example is running using the ordinary list monad. Since it's written in terms of `MonadPlus` it will work for any `(MonadTrans t, MonadPlus (t m)) => t m` as well.